# Почему плотность распределения слишком мала вверху и слишком велика справа?

Tags: python, matplotlib, density

Пробую построить диаграмму scatter с гистограммами сверху и справа, как в примере
[Пример scatter+hist на MatPlotLib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-hist-py)
Добавил в параметры `density=True`. Использую для такой диаграммы "сырые" данные, не нормированные и не центрированные.

Ожидал, что площадь на каждой гистограмме будет равна 1.
Но на верхней гистограмме значения плотностей получаются меньше, чем ожидал, а на правой - больше.
Использую код:

```
# create new axes on the right and on the top of the current axes
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

# below height and pad are in inches
ax_histx = divider.append_axes("top", 1.2, pad=0.1, sharex=ax)
ax_histy = divider.append_axes("right", 1.2, pad=0.1, sharey=ax)

# make some labels invisible
ax_histx.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=False)
ax_histy.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelleft=False)

# How many bins?
num_int = 100

n, bins, patches = ax_histx.hist(x, bins=num_int, rwidth=0.5, density=True)

n, bins, patches = ax_histy.hist(y, bins=num_int, rwidth=0.5, orientation='horizontal', density=True)

ax_histx.grid(color='black',linestyle=':', linewidth=0.1)
ax_histy.grid(color='black',linestyle=':', linewidth=0.1)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

В итоге получается следующая картинка. Видно, что сверху общая площадь будет примерно 0.03-0.04, а справа плотность >>> 1.

Что я делаю не так? Или я не правильно применяю такую диаграмму?

[image: Scatter + Hist]

**Дополнение:**
Вместо hist использовал np.histogram, bar и barh.

```
x_lim = np.max(x)-np.min(x)
counts_x, bins_x = np.histogram(x, bins = num_int)
ax_histx.bar(bins_x[:-1],  height=counts_x/len(x), width=(x_lim/num_int/2.0), align='center')
y_lim = np.max(y)-np.min(y)
counts_y, bins_y = np.histogram(y, bins = num_int)
ax_histy.barh(bins_y[:-1], height=(y_lim/num_int/2.0), width=counts_y/len(y), align='center')
```

Результат выглядит лучше

[image: Через np.histogram и bar+barh]

Answer (score 4):

Увы, функция хотя и называется hist, но в  понимании гистограммы как некого приближения функции плотности распределения не строит. Впрочим, это соответствует строгому определению гистограммы, как "количественного соотношения некоторого показателя  в виде прямоугольников, площади которых пропорциональны".  Про то, что ее можно понимать как заменитель PDF -  это уже наши хотелки. Т.е. некое представление мы получаем, а больше никто и не обещал :-)

Функция hist считает отношение количества попавших в интервал элементов к ширине самого интервала. (*"This is achieved by dividing the count by the number of observations times the bin width and not dividing by the total number of observations."*) А не к сумме всех элементов совокупности.

Поэтому, гистограмму как мы ее хотели бы получать - как  приближение PDF - она будет строить только если ширина интервала равна 1.

Если вам надо отобразить именно приближение PDF, то надо использовать соответствующие средства, например KDE- методы, благо в scipy.stats -  и даже в seaborn -  они имеются в разных вариантах реализации.